# PHP Mailer Not Delivering Mail

Tags: php, post, mailer

I'm making my first steps into the world of PHP and have started by using a small script designed for another website on my own. It's a simple mailer script and it goes as follows:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['name'])) { //form is posted

    error_reporting(-1);

    $from_email=stripslashes(nl2br($_POST['email']));

    $emaildata="";

    foreach($_POST as $key => $value)

        {

            if($key == "name")

                $emaildata.="<b>Name:</b> ".stripslashes(nl2br($value))."<br>";

            elseif($key == "email")

                $emaildata .= "<b>Email:</b> ".stripslashes(nl2br($value))."<br>";

            elseif($key == "message")

                $emaildata .= "<b>Message:</b> ".stripslashes(nl2br($value))."<br>";

            }

    $to = 'my.email@gmail.com';

    $subject = 'Quick Contact';

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";

    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";

    $headers .= 'From: <'.$from_email.'>' . "\r\n";

    $headers .= 'Bcc: test' . "\r\n";

    mail($to, $subject, $emaildata, $headers);

    echo "<script language=\"javascript\">window.location.href = 'thanks.html';</script>";

    die();

} 

?>
```

This is for the following HTML form:

```
<form role='form' style='width:100%;float:left' id="ajax-contact" method="post" action="mailer.php">
<div class='form-group'>
    <input type='text' class='form-control text-center' id="name" name="name" placeholder="What's your name, friend?" onfocus='this.placeholder=""' onblur='this.placeholder="What&#39;s your name, friend?"' required>
</div>
<div class='form-group'>
    <input type='email' class='form-control text-center' id="email" name="email" placeholder="What's your email address?" onfocus='this.placeholder=""' onblur='this.placeholder="What&#39;s your email address?"' required>
</div>
<div class='form-group'>
    <label class='text-center' style='width:100%'>Tell me about your project</label>
    <textarea class='form-control' id="message" name="message" rows='10' required></textarea>
</div>
<button type='submit' class="btn btn-josh" style='width:100%'>Send</submit>
</form>
```

Everything seems to work just fine, the form goes on to the Thank You page right after. 
The issue is that the e-mail is not showing up in my.email@gmail.com where it should be. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It´s probably not your fault; mail() just isn´t good. Use one of the known PHP mailer classes/frameworks/etc.

Comment: Check if your Server allows to send Mail also if the mail() function is allowed to send mail and last but not least check your Spam folder. if none of this work out try PHPMailer SMTP method that will allow you to use a existing email that can do the same as mail() but using other server mail. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

contact your hosting provider. most of time the hosting provder mail IP is blacklisted which cause your mail to stucked in SMTP queue of your mail server and it is not delivered to recipient.